# Blank statement when IF condition is true

Tags: c

How do I write nothing in `if` part if the condition is true?

For example:

```
if(true)
   // I want to keep this space blank or want compiler to do nothing here
else
   break;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Bad question and no search.

Comment: What's the need of the `if` if you don't need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, this is written by negating the condition:

```
if (not true)
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put a semicolon in between the `if` condition and the `else`, which is a null statement in this context:

```
if (true)
    ; // do nothing
else
    break;
```